# Unvisualize Parsons code

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## Introduction

The **Parsons code** is just a simple way to describe *pitch variations* in a piece of music, whether a note is higher or lower than the previous one.

Even if you suck at remembering tunes, you can still pretty much remember if a note goes up or down, thus the *Parsons code* can help you to identify a music using a search engine.

---

#### Description

Each variation is represented by a single character, which is one of the following:

- `R` if the note is **the same** than the previous one (stands for *"**R**epeat"*)
- `U` if the note is **higher** than the previous one (stands for *"**U**p"*)
- `D` if the note is **lower** than the previous one (stands for *"**D**own"*)

The initial note is written as `*`.

---

#### Example

Here is an example of Parsons code (beginning of *"Ode to Joy"*):

```
*RUURDDDDRUURDR
```

You can actually *visualize* it, like this:

```
      *-*                    
     /   \                   
    *     *                  
   /       \                 
*-*         *         *-*    
             \       /   \   
              *     *     *-*
               \   /         
                *-*
```

We'll call that a **contour** from now on.

The rules for drawing such countours are considered *self-explained* by the above example.

---

---

## Challenge

Now comes the real challenge.

#### Write a program that, given a contour as input, outputs its corresponding Parsons code.

You are not asked to draw the contour, but the opposite actually.
From the contour, find the original Parsons code.

---

#### Rules

- The usual rules for code golfing apply
- **The shortest program in number of bytes wins**
- The input is a contour, and the output shall be a valid Parsons code
- Details about extra whitespace for the input are irrelevant, do whatever works best for you
- You are not allowed to hardcode, one way or another, parts of the output and / or the program using extra whitespace because of the previous rule

#### Notes

- [**This might be useful for testing**](http://www.musipedia.org/melodic_contour.html)
- The corresponding Parsons code for `*` is `*`
- An empty string is not a valid contour
- A Parsons code **always** starts with `*`

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58759/3808

Comment: So it must start with `*` which doesn't do anything?

Comment: What do you mean? when the input is just `*`? Nope. It should print `*` I suppose. I'll add this corner case.

Comment: I mean, is `RUUR` invalid? Or it is valid as  `*RUUR`?

Comment: @nicael Yes, it **must** start with `*`. Always.

Comment: Ok, that's clear.

Comment: Are we allowed to have trailing whitespace? If so, how much?

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55593/42545

Comment: Can I output a list?

Comment: @Maltysen No, Parsons code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>28</s> <s>25</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*2 byes saved thanks to @Jakube.*

```
s+\*@L"RDU"-VFtBxR\*%2C.z
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2B%5C%2a%40L%22RDU%22-VFtBxR%5C%2a%252C.z&input=++++++%2a-%2a++++++++++++++++++++%0A+++++%2F+++%5C+++++++++++++++++++%0A++++%2a+++++%2a++++++++++++++++++%0A+++%2F+++++++%5C+++++++++++++++++%0A%2a-%2a+++++++++%2a+++++++++%2a-%2a++++%0A+++++++++++++%5C+++++++%2F+++%5C+++%0A++++++++++++++%2a+++++%2a+++++%2a-%2a%0A+++++++++++++++%5C+++%2F+++++++++%0A++++++++++++++++%2a-%2a++++++++++&debug=0).

Comment: It does not work with `*` as input. The output is `*0` while it should be just `*`. An evil wild trailing zero appeared.

Comment: @HelgevonKoch fixed

Comment: You've swapped `U` and `D` by the way. Otherwise, well done.

Comment: @HelgevonKoch oops

Answer (score 24):

## CJam, 21 bytes

```
qN/:.e>(o2%:i"DRXU"f=
```

Fold the lines (`:`) by vectorizing (`.`) a character-wise maximum operation `e>`. Since there is only one non-space character in each column, this one will be the result, as space has a smaller ASCII code than all printable non-space characters.

Unshift and print the first asterisk `(o`, then map every other (`2%`) remaining char to `UDR` using modular indexing.

### Old solution (29 bytes)

```
'*qN/z2%'*f#0+2ew);::-"RDU"f=
```

`qN/` gets input lines. `z` transposes this character matrix. `2%` drops every odd row. `'*f#` finds the index of the asterisk in each row. `0+2ew);` gets all successive pairs of indices. `::-` computes their differences, and `"RDU"f=` maps them to letters (via modular indexing: `0 → R`, `2 → U`, `-2 ≡ 1 → D`). The leading `'*` prepends the asterisk.

**EDIT**: I changed `2ew` to `0+2ew);` to work around CJam not handling `ew` (successive slices) on lists that are too short. This makes the code work for the input string `*`.

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%27*qN%2Fz2%25%27*f%232ew%3A%3A-%22RDU%22f%3D&input=%20%20%20%20%20%20*-*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%2F%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20*%20%20%20%20%20*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A*-*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*-*%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*%20%20%20%20%20*%20%20%20%20%20*-*%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%20%20%20%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*-*%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20), or watch it in action:

Comment: This is really awesome to watch.

Comment: I agree! +1 for the code, wish I could +10 for the GIF.

Comment: BTW, I like the smiley at code length 17 `:-p`

Comment: I agree, this is awesome to watch. It does not work with `*` as input though. I get a nice `RuntimeException` instead.

Comment: Ugh, I consider that a CJam bug: `[X]2ew` should return `[]` instead of erroring out. I'll add a workaround, though.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>129</s> <s>108</s> <s>98</s> 86 bytes

There are probably several ways to golf this, but I rather like that I got it all down to one line.

**Edit:** Now using `''.translate()`

**Edit:** With many thanks to [wnnmaw](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30170/wnnmaw).

**Edit:** I changed the input format to an array of strings instead of a newline-separated string to save bytes. Also, in the last edit, I mixed up `U` and `R`, so I fixed that.

```
lambda a:'*'+"".join(('UR'[j<'/']+'D')[j>'/']for l in zip(*a)for j in l if j in'-/\\')
```

Input must be an array of strings. For the example above, this looks something like:

```
["      *-*                    ","     /   \                   ","    *     *                  ","   /       \                 ","*-*         *         *-*    ","             \       /   \   ","              *     *     *-*","               \   /         ","                *-*          "]
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(a):
    s = ''
    for c in zip(*a):           # transpose
        for d in c:             # for each letter in column c
            if e in "-/\\":     # if that letter is either -,/,\
                if e < '/':     # if < '/' (same as if == '-')
                    s += "R"
                elif e > '/':   # if > '/' (same as if == '\')
                    s += "D"
                else:           # if == '/'
                    s += "U"
        return "*" + s          # in the code we ''.join() it all together
                                # in this ungolfing, we add to an empty string
```

Comment: I don't want to make a new answer because I borrowed a lot from yours, but `lambda s:'*'+"".join((('D','R')[j=='-'],'U')[j=='/']for l in zip(*s.split('\n'))for j in l if j in'\\/-')` clocks in at 105 bytes.  Main difference is using a tuple conditional instead of translate

Comment: Thanks @wnnmaw! I think I can golf that down even further!

Comment: Nice golfing on the conditional in the front, that is super clever!

Comment: Ah shucks. Thanks for the tip @wnnmaw

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 87 bytes

Requires trailing spaces in the input so that all lines are the same length.

```
$><<?*+$<.readlines.map(&:chars).transpose.join.gsub(/./,{?-=>:R,?/=>:U,?\\=>:D}).strip
```

Comment: Surely this is malicious code, as it contains `>:D`.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 38 bytes <s>40 41 45 46 48</s>

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
'*+U·y £Yu ?"RUD"g1+(XrS c -47 g):P} q
```

If there was a trim command this would be only 38 bytes ;-; will add explanation when I'm done golfing. The `:P` is not the program trying to be funny, it's actually the program ignoring characters that aren't important.

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=JyorVbd5IG1AWXUgPyJSVUQiZyhYclNQIGMgLTQ3IGcgKzEgOlB9IHE=&input=IiAgICAgICotKiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgLyAgIFwgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAqICAgICAqICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgIC8gICAgICAgXCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiotKiAgICAgICAgICogICAgICAgICAqLSogICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICBcICAgICAgIC8gICBcICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgKiAgICAgKiAgICAgKi0qCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIFwgICAvICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAqLSogICAgICAgICAgIg==)

Comment: When I saw that there was a challenge practically requiring an array transpose, and that Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ had answered it, I knew it had to be Japt.

Comment: BTW, I'll add in a trim function at `x` and transpose and rotate functions at `y` and `z` (split at newlines, use the array function, join with newlines)

Comment: You could save two bytes like this: `Yu ?"RUD"g1+(XrS c -47 g):P`

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks, down to under 40 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 89 bytes

```
import Data.List
m '/'="U"
m '-'="R"
m '\\'="D"
m _=""
('*':).(>>=(>>=m)).transpose.lines
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> ('*':).(>>=(>>=m)).transpose.lines $ "      *-*                    \n     /   \\                   \n    *     *                  \n   /       \\                 \n*-*         *         *-*    \n             \\       /   \\   \n              *     *     *-*\n               \\   /         \n                *-*          "
"*RUURDDDDRUURDR"

*Main> ('*':).(>>=(>>=m)).transpose.lines $ "*"
"*"
```

Transpose the input and replace the characters `/`/`-`/`\` with singleton strings `"U"`/`"R"`/`"D"`. All other chars are replaced by empty strings `""`, which later disappear by concatenating everything. Finally, prepend the asterisk `*`.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 103 bytes

```
"*"<>(Differences@Position[Thread@Characters@StringSplit[#,"
"],"*"][[;;,2]]/.{-2->"U",0->"R",2->"D"})&
```

Quite short, considering that this is a string-processing challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 90

An anonymous function. It scans the input string char by char, taking into accout the position in the current line. Doing this, it builds an output array subsituting `U D R` for `/ \ -` at the right place

```js
c=>[...c].map(c=>c>'*'?t[i++]=c>'/'?'D':c<'/'?'R':'U':c<' '?i=0:++i,t=['*'],i=0)&&t.join``
```

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 62 bytes

```
r=@(s)[85-(s<14)*3-(s>59)*17,''];@(p)r(sum(p(:,2:2:end)-32))
```

This requires the input to be a rectangular (same number of characters in each row). E.g.

```
    ['      *-*                    ';    '     /   \                   ';    '    *     *                  ';    '   /       \                 ';    '*-*         *         *-*    ';    '             \       /   \   ';    '              *     *     *-*';    '               \   /         ';    '                *-*          '];
```

#### Explanation

```
sum(p(:,2:2:end)-32)        % exctract every second column, substract 32 (spaces->zeros) 
                            % and sum column wise (results in a vector of 3 different values)
[85-(s<14)*3-(s>59)*17,'']  % map each of the values to the corresponding value of the letter and convert back to characters
```